# Casting a list of an object to a list of super types

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have the following class structure:

```
public interface RangeData {
   public int getMaxVal();
   public int getMinVal();
}

public class IncomeRange implements RangeData {
  ....
}

//In a utilities class
public RangeData findRangeData(List<RangeData> list, int value) {
  ....code....
}
```

The problems crops up when I have a list of Income ranges, yet I cannot cast to a list of RangeData.  If this was a single item it would be no problem.

```
List<IncomeRanges> incomes = xxx();  //returns the proper data.

//Yet this does not work.
findRangeData(incomes,55);
```

I've tried to do all kind of casts on it, but nothing seems to work.  How can I get this to work?

Comment: In general, you cannot and should not cast a List<String> to a List<Object> (same with arrays). Once you have an Object[] from a String[], you put any kind of Object in. Same thing goes to a less extent with Generic casting to super type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java Generics are [**invariant**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29). This means that, given two concrete classes, `A` and `B`, `SomeClass<A>` has no relationship to `SomeClass<B>`, even if `B` is a subtype of `A`.

So, `List<RangeData>` is not a supertype of `List<IncomeRanges>`. Instead, you should use an [upper bounded wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html), like this:

```
public RangeData findRangeData(List<? extends RangeData> list, int value) {
    ....code....
}
```

For more information, you can check the documentation on [Generics, Inheritance, and Subtypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon Anderson's answer, `List<A>` and `List<B>` are unrelated types, even if `B extends A`. To see why, consider what would happen if it were the case that `List<B>` is a subclass of `List<A>`. We could do:

```
class Animal{}
class Dog extends Animal{}

List<Dog> d = new List<Dog>();
((List<Animal>) a).add(new Animal()); //Uh oh
```

But this is a problem because a, truly a list of `Dog`s, contains a non-dog object.

How about the other way? If we can't say that `List<B>` is a subclass of `List<A>`, maybe we can say that `List<A>` is a subclass of `List<B>`. That has the opposite problem, however:

```
class Animal{}
class Dog extends Animal{}
class Cat extends Animal();

List<Animal> a = new List<Animal>();
a.add(new Cat());
Dog dog = ((List<Dog>) d).getFirst(); //Uh oh
```

But the element we get out of d isn't necessarily a `Dog` - in this case, it's a `Cat`. So this is a problem as well.

To sum up, the generic type of *mutable* collections in Java such as `List`s is **invariant** - `List<A>` is completely unrelated to `List<B>` regardless of the relation between `A` and `B`, if there is any.

Using bounded wildcards, as Anderson does in his answer, is a solution to this problem. This does restrict the valid operations you're allowed to perform. For example, you can't add elements to a `List<? extends A>`, because there's no guarantees that the element you're adding is a valid member of the list you're adding it to. However, it opens the possibilities of what lists you can conform to the type. `List<Cat>` and `List<Dog>`, while unrelated to `List<Animal>`, are both valid subtypes of `List<? extends Animal>`. For any `List<? extends Animal>`, any element retrieved from the list will be an instance of Animal (or potentially one of its subtypes).